# Returning values from 2 select statements in Oracle Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Homework question that I'm stuck on.

I need to create a Procedure called dept_info with a department id as the IN parameter with department name and full name (concat of first and last name) of the manager of that department as the OUT parameters to be passed back to the invoking program. the procedure should be within the PL SQL block.

There are two tables to be used: departments which holds the department ID, department name, and manager ID, and employees, which holds employee ID (which would be the same as manager ID), first name, and last name.

The executable section should print out the info for department ID 100.

My code so far is:

```
DECLARE
    dept_id departments.department_id%TYPE;
    dept_name VARCHAR(30);
    mgr_id NUMBER(4);
    full_name VARCHAR(100);

    PROCEDURE dept_info(
    dep_id IN departments.department_id%TYPE,
    dep_name OUT departments.department_name%TYPE,
    full_name OUT employees.first_name%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
        SELECT department_name, manager_id INTO dept_name, mgr_id FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE department_id = dept_id;
        SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS full_name INTO full_name FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE employee_id = mgr_id;
    END dept_info;
BEGIN
    dept_info(100, dept_name, full_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dept_id || dept_name || full_name);
END;
```

This returns a "no data found" which means my data from my SELECT and INTO statements are not working properly. Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Is the expected row present?

Comment: If I run a select statement for the needed data, and join the employees and department tables on employee_id = manager_id for department_id = 100, the desired row returns, yes.

Comment: Sample data would help a lot.

Comment: without more information a stab in the dark, but you have a variable dept_id and a parameter to your procedure called dept_id, at best this is bad practice, at worst it may be getting confused between the two. A naming convention to identify variables / parameters ect is highly recomended eg (p_blah... is a parameter v_blah.... is a variable)

Comment: @ShaunPeterson one is dep_id and one is dept_id, but can see your point how this would be very confusing.  This is the root cause of the issue though.  In my select statement, the INTO should have been into dep_id and = dep_id rather than dept_id.  I will post the code below.  Thank you.

Comment: Quite correct, sorry reading on a mobile and variables were close enough to look the same.... Glad you found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More clear naming for the variables would be helpful, but in the end I used the improper variable in the SELECT statements.  Correct code:

```
DECLARE
    dept_id departments.department_id%TYPE := 100;
    dept_name VARCHAR(30);
    mgr_id NUMBER(4);
    full_name VARCHAR(46);
    PROCEDURE dept_info(
    dep_id IN departments.department_id%TYPE,
    dep_name OUT departments.department_name%TYPE,
    full_name OUT employees.first_name%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
        SELECT department_name, manager_id INTO dep_name, mgr_id FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE department_id = dep_id;
        SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS full_name INTO full_name FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE employee_id = mgr_id;
    END dept_info;
BEGIN
    dept_info(100, dept_name, full_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dept_id || dept_name || full_name);
END;
```